# Error when importing tensorflow, ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, python-3.6

**System information:**

win10

python 3.6.2

tensorflow 1.11.0

numpy 1.15.3

conda 4.3.30

cuda 8.0

cudnn 6.0

pip 18.1

I created a new environment with python3.6.2 in anaconda and  installed tensorflow with pip, and met with such a problem, thanks for help.

> Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 12:30:02) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> > import tensorflow as tf
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\SZF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "C:\Users\SZF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\SZF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "I:\Anaconda\envs\envPyTF\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "I:\Anaconda\envs\envPyTF\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Users\SZF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 22, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>     File "C:\Users\SZF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "C:\Users\SZF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\SZF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "C:\Users\SZF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\SZF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "I:\Anaconda\envs\envPyTF\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "I:\Anaconda\envs\envPyTF\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try installing it with conda
[tensorflow](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow) 
[tensorflow-gpu](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu)